# Automated tests orchestrator

Tags: automated-testing

Summary: I'm using TFS as a build server and I familiar with MTM. What I am looking for is an alternative to MTM for steps 3 -5 .
I'm looking for an automated testing tool (free or opensource) that can do the following:

1. Manage test machines
2. Run the tests on the machines (according to configuration)
3. can either run shell commands on the agents or integrate with Seleniun and or C#

A plus if:
 - can integrate with TFS
 - Have easy reporting servers integration.

any ideas?

Comment: I agree with @Niels you must provide more context. Tools range from QualiSystems end to end suite, CI tools like Jenkins that can be modified to manage labs down to programming something on your own using remote execution frameworks (I used STAF a long time ago)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a [Build server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software).
A typical build flow looks like this:

1. Get code from TFS
2. Build Code
3. Run unit-tests
4. Spawn nodes for integration tests
5. Run integration and or Selenium tests

Microsoft has testing tools to integration such a process tightly within TFS:

- Set up Team Foundation Build Service: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee259687.aspx
- Test on a lab environment with test manager: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635157.aspx

There are also free build servers like:

- [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) (Open Source)
- [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) (First 20 builds and 3 agents are free)

It should be possible to script anything from starting machines, running tests and deployments with these build tools.

Comment: I'll be more specific.
I'm using TFS as a build server and I familiar with MTM.
What I am looking for is an alternative to MTM for steps 3 -5 .

Comment: Why do you look for an alternative?

Comment: People were not happy with the POC we did with the MTM, so I would like to look for alternative and weight whats the best option for us to use.

Comment: Maybe good to add this extra context to your question and also any other research you did. I would have given a different answer probably :) Still I think you should research build-servers and command-line tools to script the action you want to execute. Most actions are script-able with command-line tools, thus the build server should be enough to drive these actions.

Comment: Please give more details on why "People were not happy" in your question.